# Removing a drag item from an Angular Materials cdkDropList when the element is dragged far away from the container

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a cdkDropList with 4 draggable items inside. The problem is that I want to be able to drag an item completely out of the drop list once I drag it far away from its container. Currently it doesnt matter how far you drag the item, the item still returns within the boundary of the drop list

As it is shown in the documentation of Angular materials [Link to the example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting), it is possible to move items within the drop list and from/to a drop list to another.

I want to know if the behavior that im looking for even possible?

*In short: I want to be able to freely move the item in the page (without the item returning back to the drop list container once i release the mouse button). In other words, to detach the item from the drop list.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `cdkDrag` directive?

it should allow you to move the choosen element freely on the site.

Comment: `cdkDrag` works on its own however, I loose the ability of sorting the items and the stickiness of the items to the horizontal axis. I want to detach the item from the drop list when i drag it after a certain point.